# Previous iteration-memoization with CRTP-interfaces

Tags: c++, templates, memoization, crtp

I have a Curiously Recurring Template Pattern (CRTP) interface-class where I want to memoize evaluations for all methods defined by the derived classes. I also have return values whose types are template-defined. Example:

```
template <class Derived, class Ret1, class Ret2>
class memoization_class
{
    int operator_iter, Eval_1_iter, Eval_2_iter;
    double data_operator;
    Ret1 data_Eval_1;
    Ret2 data_Eval_2;
public:

    //Desired memoization:
    double operator()(const double &arg, const int& iter)
    {
        if (iter != operator_iter)
        {
            data_operator = static_cast<Derived *>(this)->operator(arg);
            operator_iter = iter;
            return data_operator;
        }
        else
        {
            return data_operator;
        }
    }

    //Want to create the same buffer for an arbitrary return type, for an arbitrary amount of methods
    Ret1 Eval_1(const double &arg, const int& iter)
    {
        return static_cast<Derived *>(this)->Eval_1(arg);
    }

    Ret2 Eval_2(const double &arg, const int& iter)
    {
        return static_cast<Derived *>(this)->Eval_2(arg);
    }
};
```

Is it possible to generalize this behaviour to something like this:

```
template <class Derived, class Ret1, class Ret2>
class memoization_class
{
    int operator_iter, Eval_1_iter, Eval_2_iter;
    double data_operator;
    Ret1 data_Eval_1;
    Ret2 data_Eval_2;
public:

    double operator()(const double &arg, const int& iter)
    {
        return memoize(&static_cast<Derived *>(this)->operator(), arg, iter);
    }
    
    //..
};
```

Edit: Here is the application for the problem. It uses Eigen, and may return Sparse or Dense matrices/vectors. (The class provides functions for optimizing nonlinear problems)

MatrixBase is in this case a substitute for Vec in order to allow Eigen to pass all kinds of unevaluated expressions.

```
#ifndef OBJECTIVE_HPP
#define OBJECTIVE_HPP
#include "EigenDataTypes.hpp"

// template <class Base, class Mat>
// using is_Base = std::enable_if_t<std::is_base_of<Base, Mat>::value>;

// template <class Derived, class Vec, class Mat, typename Enable = void>
// struct objective;

template <class Derived, class Vec, class Mat>
struct objective
{
protected:
    int Nx_, nnzh_;

public:
    objective(const int &Nx, const int &nnzh) : Nx_(Nx), nnzh_(nnzh) {}

    template <typename T>
    inline scalar operator()(const MatrixBase<T> &x)
    {
        return static_cast<Derived *>(this)->operator()(x);
    }

    template <typename T>
    inline Vec Eval_grad(const MatrixBase<T> &x)
    {
        return static_cast<Derived *>(this)->Eval_grad(x);
    }

    template <typename T>
    inline Mat Eval_hessian(const MatrixBase<T> &x)
    {
        return static_cast<Derived *>(this)->Eval_hessian(x);
    }

    template <typename T>
    inline scalar operator()(const SparseMatrixBase<T> &x)
    {
        return static_cast<Derived *>(this)->operator()(x);
    }

    template <typename T>
    inline Vec Eval_grad(const SparseMatrixBase<T> &x)
    {
        return static_cast<Derived *>(this)->Eval_grad(x);
    }

    template <typename T>
    inline Mat Eval_hessian(const SparseMatrixBase<T> &x)
    {
        return static_cast<Derived *>(this)->Eval_hessian(x);
    }

    inline int Get_Nx()
    {
        return Nx_;
    }

    inline int Get_nnzh()
    {
        return nnzh_;
    }
};
```

EigenDataTypes.hpp:

```
#ifndef EIGENDATATYPES_H
#define EIGENDATATYPES_H

#include <Eigen/Dense>
#include <Eigen/Sparse>

using scalar = Eigen::Matrix<double, 1, 1>;

using Eigen::MatrixXd;
using Eigen::VectorXd;
using spVec = Eigen::SparseVector<double>;
using spMat = Eigen::SparseMatrix<double>;
using dVec = Eigen::VectorXd;
using dMat = Eigen::MatrixXd;
using Eigen::MatrixBase;

using Eigen::SparseMatrixBase;
using Triplet = Eigen::Triplet<double>;
#endif
```

Edit 2: Here is my rather verbose implementation of memoization for the objective-class. (It checks for change in input x instead of iteration-change):

```
template <class Data>
struct memData
{

    dVec x;
    Data data;
    memData(const int &Nx) : x(Nx)
    {
    }
};

inline bool
is_memoized(const dVec &x, const dVec &x_mem)
{
    return ((x - x_mem).array().abs() <= std::numeric_limits<double>::epsilon()).all();
}

template <class Derived, class Vec, class Mat>
struct objective_memoized : public objective<objective_memoized<Derived, Vec, Mat>, Vec, Mat>
{

protected:
    int &Nx_ = objective<objective_memoized<Derived, Vec, Mat>, Vec, Mat>::Nx_;
    int &nnzh_ = objective<objective_memoized<Derived, Vec, Mat>, Vec, Mat>::nnzh_;

    memData<scalar> mem_operator;
    memData<Vec> mem_Eval_grad;
    memData<Mat> mem_Eval_hessian;

public:
    objective_memoized(const int &Nx, const int &nnzh) : objective<objective_memoized<Derived, Vec, Mat>, Vec, Mat>(Nx, nnzh),
                                                         mem_operator(Nx),
                                                         mem_Eval_grad(Nx),
                                                         mem_Eval_hessian(Nx)
    {
    }

    objective_memoized(const int &Nx, const int &Ns, const int &nnzh) : objective<objective_memoized<Derived, Vec, Mat>, Vec, Mat>(Nx, nnzh),
                                                                        mem_operator(Nx + Ns),
                                                                        mem_Eval_grad(Nx + Ns),
                                                                        mem_Eval_hessian(Nx + Ns)
    {
    }

    template <typename T>
    inline scalar operator()(const MatrixBase<T> &x)
    {
        if (!is_memoized(x, mem_operator.x))
        {
            mem_operator.data = static_cast<Derived *>(this)->operator()(x);
            mem_operator.x = x;
        }
        return mem_operator.data;
    }

    template <typename T>
    inline Vec Eval_grad(const MatrixBase<T> &x)
    {
        if (!is_memoized(x, mem_Eval_grad.x))
        {
            mem_Eval_grad.data = static_cast<Derived *>(this)->Eval_grad(x);
            mem_Eval_grad.x = x;
        }
        return mem_Eval_grad.data;
    }

    template <typename T>
    inline Mat Eval_hessian(const MatrixBase<T> &x)
    {
        if (!is_memoized(x, mem_Eval_hessian.x))
        {
            mem_Eval_hessian.data = static_cast<Derived *>(this)->Eval_hessian(x);
            mem_Eval_hessian.x = x;
        }
        return mem_Eval_hessian.data;
    }

    template <typename T>
    inline scalar operator()(const SparseMatrixBase<T> &x)
    {
        if (!is_memoized(x, mem_operator.x))
        {
            mem_operator.data = static_cast<Derived *>(this)->operator()(x);
            mem_operator.x = x;
        }
        return mem_operator.data;
    }

    template <typename T>
    inline Vec Eval_grad(const SparseMatrixBase<T> &x)
    {
        if (!is_memoized(x, mem_Eval_grad.x))
        {
            mem_Eval_grad.data = static_cast<Derived *>(this)->Eval_grad(x);
            mem_Eval_grad.x = x;
        }
        return mem_Eval_grad.data;
    }

    template <typename T>
    inline Mat Eval_hessian(const SparseMatrixBase<T> &x)
    {
        if (!is_memoized(x, mem_Eval_hessian.x))
        {
            mem_Eval_hessian.data = static_cast<Derived *>(this)->Eval_hessian(x);
            mem_Eval_hessian.x = x;
        }
        return mem_Eval_hessian.data;
    }
};
```

TLDR; I want to return stored data if it has been evaluated previously this iteration, or evaluate, store & return if not. Can I use one function to define this for all return types?

Comment: So there should be one memoized value per used return type? All the functions take the same parameter types? Maybe you could show an example of how the wanted class should be used, with desired results.

Comment: I would write `memoize<Sig>(lamda)` which returns a memoizing wrapper around the lambda. Then much of the CRTP stuff becomes orthogonal noise.

Comment: Could you elaborate on memoize<Sig>(lambda)? I was unable to pass static_casted methods as input arguments when I tried to generalize the memoization

Comment: Well, `static_cast<Derived *>(this)->operator()` is an expression of the sort `p->func` which is not valid without following call arguments when it names a non-static member function. The closest you can get is `&Derived::operator()`.

Comment: I do want this thing to be statically configured, so I suspect that it must be passed as a template argument instead

Comment: I think the `memoize` idea would go something like this: https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ebb86cb86246fac4 . Unfortunately, I don't see a way to make those into members of the CRTP base without some type erasure which would lose the inline-able benefit of basic CRTP, since the types of such members need to be determined before `Derived` is a complete type.