# Pass static_casted method as template parameter

Tags: c++, templates, crtp, static-cast

I'm trying to generalize the usage of previous-iteration memoization in CRTP-interfaces, where many of the methods refer to derived classes. The CRTP-methods looks like this:

```
inline RetVal method1(const Arg& x)
{
   return static_cast<Derived*>(this)->method1(x);
}
```

I want to use a generic memoizer that achieves something like this:

```
private:
memoizer<&static_cast<Derived*>(this)->method1, RetVal> memoized_method1;

public:
inline RetVal method1(const Arg& x)
{
   return memoized_method1(x);
}
```

I've gotten tips in this thread: [Previous iteration-memoization with CRTP-interfaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69595836/previous-iteration-memoization-with-crtp-interfaces?noredirect=1#comment123022514_69595836), which provides a solution to memoization, but I'm not able to pass the correct method. Is it possible to achieve this?

Edit:
I have this:
[image: CRTP-Interface Implementation]

And want this:
[image: CRTP-Interface desired memoized Implementation]

Edit 2:
I managed to create a class to contain the operation:

```
template <typename RetType, typename Derived, RetType (*Method)(const dVec&)>
class memoize
{
public:
    constexpr memoize(Derived DerivedClass)
        : DerivedClass_(DerivedClass) 
        {
        }
    
    template <typename T>
    RetType operator()(const T &x)
    {
        if (x.isApprox(mem_x_))
        {
            mem_x_ = x;
            mem_data_ = DerivedClass_->Method(x);
        }

        return mem_data_;
    }

private:
    Derived DerivedClass_;
    RetType mem_data_;
    dVec mem_x_;
};
```

Unfortunately when I call this in my implementation it is not considered static:

```
auto mem_operator = memoize<scalar, Derived, &Derived::operator()>(static_cast<Derived*>(this));

 error: non-static data member declared with placeholder ‘auto’
   48 |     auto mem_operator = memoize<scalar, Derived, &Derived::operator()>(static_cast<Derived*>(this));
```

Comment: You should try to reduce the original code so that we can better understand what the problem is.

Comment: Should it be `memoizer<&Derived::method1, RetVal>`, and `memoized_method1(static_cast<Derived*>(this), x);`?